# if I delete IOS folder from flutter project, will it still work on android?

Tags: flutter

you can see the both folder IOS and Android, and if I delete the folder IOS, will it work only for android?

[image]

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't worry, you can delete the ios directory.

In Flutter, every specific platform has a dedicated directory (ios, android, web, macos, windows, linux). Each directory uses the same code inside lib (Flutter, app-related code). Meaning, if you want to delete a specific platform, just delete its dedicated directory.

Comment: Thank you, i just checked all file one by one, now i understand

Comment: Great, I'll be happy if you accept my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Your project will definitely work on Android. Each folder for each platform represents the manipulation of the codebase for the desired platform. You can delete each folder without happening any errors.

Furthermore, If you are creating the project with android studio, you can select which platforms you are targeting. Then folders for the selected platforms will be made.